# Display search results in a Fragment, not Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a search in an existing app following the example here:
http://www.materialdoc.com/search-filter/

The app uses fragment replace to change displays and so instead of creating another activity I am trying to display the results in another fragment. The problem is that when a search string is entered and the magnifying class is it, no handler is called.

I think the main problem is in this code in `MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
    // ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchListFragment.class); // results in NPE
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
```

Calling `setSearchableInfo()` with `MainActivity.class` does nothing and calling it with `SearchListFragment.class` results in an NPE.

I've created an SSCCE here:
https://github.com/emnrd-ito/SearchFragmentTest

Can you see how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. There are pieces that you are missing from the example that you reference such as defining a search `Activity` in the manifest and processing the search `Intent`. Are you trying to use a search `Fragment` in place of an `Activity`? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm trying to use MainActivity, not another activity. Currently, the app display a list of all employees, the searched employee list is some subset of that, so it would see that I could somehow display that list in a manner similar to the all employee list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get you most of the way there:

Change your manifest as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

This includes a new launchmode or "singleTop", the "Search" intent, and the `meta-data` that is needed.

**In MainActivity:**

**OnCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
//  ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchListFragment.class);
//  searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));

    return true;
}
```

**onNewIntent**

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onNewIntent", "here!");
}
```

You will have to expand `onNewIntent` to do your search stuff. The `Intent` contains the search criteria. See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchingYourData) for details.

I think those are all of the modifications. It is not a complete solution, but I hope that it gets you on the road to figuring out the rest.

Comment: I will try this, but I'm not sure it will work. I tried playing with `onNewIntent` and couldn't get it to work because it is called only when the Activity is restarted.

Comment: Make sure you get `android:launchMode="singleTop"` into the manifest, otherwise the search will go through `onCreate` and that is not what you want. This will work.

Comment: I've implemented the code you've suggested. It's better in that `onNewIntent` is being called now. When I tried it before I think I didn't have it set correctly in the manifest (based on looking at your code). There is still a problem in that the list is not displayed. The title is displayed, but not the list. In debugging, I see the list in the adapter is being built, but somehow just not displayed. I've pushed the changes to the github project so you can see.

Comment: Got it. The adapter was missing a rather important line. Thanks for your expertise.